# How to avoid "&#13;" (CR) in XMLSignature generated from webapp running on Tomcat 8.5 with JDK8

Tags: java-8, x509certificate, tomcat8, carriage-return, xml-signature

I'm experiencing a problem with java XMLSignature: when I try to generate the signature and then sign the XML file, an **unwanted** HTML-like Carriage Return ("&#13;") is placed at then end of each line both in SignatureValue and X509Certificate.

Example:

`zLxzCI14qHxBCXamm46Rj7nFoIDM6RTvUvUOdiQN9NkK96GzbxCJjpQVNAXduWwcMwDSVP2ouO0N&#13; 9NSnL+TNZyU62x6Lw0N6FFbzGIzfs9HDnrw531kfpDhOBZCB85h7MGcAJmOvhy5/Gv8qgFw2DVED&#13;`

I've tried to solve the problem adding the following lines to the code, based on some suggestions I found on the web:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.ignoreLineBreaks", "true");
System.setProperty("org.apache.xml.security.ignoreLineBreaks", "true");
```

but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem editing the **setenv.sh** script on Tomcat (at `${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/setenv.sh`) appending

`-Dcom.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.ignoreLineBreaks=true`

to the string of properties defined in `CATALINA_OPTS`.

With this setting Carriage Returns (CR) **and Line Feeds** (LF) were removed only inside the `<Signature>` tag of the resulting XML file.